# Decrypting data received from iOS fail on big data - PHP

Tags: php, encryption

I use aesEncryptWithStaticIV() from [here](https://gist.github.com/tlarevo/63840cdd421937ba9174) to encrypt data.

For text data "test", function give me encrypted result `065TnFFNwQFRjPZk6l8luw==`
and PHP successfuly decrypt it.

But with 'real' data

> eg: "`progression|*|D4E1B270-06DD-4A|*|25|*|342|*|159|*|10|*|1457454939636.0`"

php don't decrypt correctly the data, give me "`m/^(_2<=Q9KBu#~<,s+z'sS)\\nrMc-o|PCxJNo/`"

here is php decrypt function :

```
function decrypt($data) {
    $code = base64_decode ( urldecode ( $data ) );
    $iv = $this->iv;
    $td = mcrypt_module_open('rijndael-128', '', 'cbc', $iv);
    mcrypt_generic_init($td, $this->key, $iv);
    $decrypted = mdecrypt_generic($td, $code);
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
    mcrypt_module_close($td);
    return trim(preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $decrypted));
}
```

and here procedure for encrypt data (sended by http post) :

> let dump = try! data.stringByAddingPercentEncodingForRFC3986()!.aesEncrypt()

I don't understand why it's only work with short/simple data ?

Comment: **Never use CBC mode with a static IV**. It's deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. You should at the very least use a random IV. It doesn't have to be secret, so you can send it along with the ciphertext. Although, it is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme.

Comment: I came here to say what @ArtjomB. said.

Comment: Thanks both for advise, i will change my code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove urldecode() from php, don't understand why but it corrompt the data, but visually there no differences...